# ¿Cómo guardar los datos de un array en una colección en un registro individual de una tabla?

Tags: laravel

Tengo un formulario donde solicito varios datos, entre ellos varios campos tipo file para subir imagenes, esa data de file lo recibo como un arreglo (Array) y así los recibo en el controlador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
(imagen 01)

Luego en el controlador (imagen 02) le cambio el tamaño a cada una de esas imagenes, y las almaceno en una carpeta (directorio) y luego guardo cada uno de los nombres que el controlador le asigna a las imagenes, en campos diferente de la tabla, ejemplo: file1 (La primera imagen cargada), file2 (la segunda imagen cargada), así hasta llegar a file11 si hay esa cantidad de imagenes cargadas por el usuario (imagen 03).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
(imagen 02)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
(imagen 03)

Y lo que requiero hacer es que cada una de esos nombres de imagenes se guarden en un registro nuevo, como hace referencia la siguiente imagen (imagen 04):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
(imagen 02)

Como se puede notar, cada accommodationtiene varias fotos, aquí una por registro y se identifica con el accommodation_id

Otra solución podría ser guardar enuna solo campo de la tabla los nombres de las imagenes en un array, ejemplo: images/accommodations/qweery.jpg,images/accommodations/ujeyegd.jpg,images/accommodations/jduffgs.jpg y luego puedo obtenerlas con un explode, pero no se como hacerlo en ambas opciones, estuve haciendo varias cosas sin resultados favorables, pude ciclos for dentro del bucle, array_push para $path, pero enambas opciones me guarda solo una imagen (El nombre).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías crear un nuevo registro para cada iteración, no sé como se llame la tabla o modelo en donde guardas esas imágenes, pero la llamaremos `Model`:

```
foreach($request->file('image') as $key => $file){
   $img = Image::make($file)->resize(900, 500);
   $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('images/accommodations', $file);
   // Aquí el cambio
   Model::create([
       'accommodation_id' => $accommodation->id,
       'Photo'            => $path
   ]);
}
```

Si no me equivoco, estás creando nuevas columnas con `fill()` debido a que el nombre del atributo es **dinámico**. Y, si no existe, lo crea.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar los $casts en el modelo. Es decir, puedes hacer que eloquent haga ese trabajo por ti, ejemplo:

Supongamos que tienes un modelo llamado Photo

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Photo extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'description', 'images'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'images' => 'array'
    ];  
}
```

En el ejemplo anterior se declara que el campo images debe ser un arreglo, eloquent realiza la serialización automáticamente.

En este caso podrá realizar algo como esto:

```
Photo::create([
    'name' => 'nombre',
    'description' => 'descripción'
    'images' => [
        'imagen1' => 'path_imagen1',
        'imagen2' => 'path_imagen2',
        'imagen3' => 'path_imagen3',
        'imagen4' => 'path_imagen4'
    ]
]);
```

Para más información puedes consultar la documentación oficial de Laravel:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-serialization#date-serialization